# Auth0. Create user in db after registration | Angular SPA + ASP.NET Core 7 Web API + Auth0

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, single-page-application, auth0

I am currently working on a project where I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API backend and Angular frontend. I need to combine those 2 apps with Auth0. Due to business requirements, user after login/register need to create profile in system.

In every example I see that after user register is redirecting to SPA frontend app and then we can get accessToken and reach endpoints in API. But in our combo user profile in db not exists but someone have accessToken. And I have doubts how to fix it.

In ideal scenario I want to intercept registration success token with some API/callback endpoint in backend app, base on this create user entity, set custom claim like ex `profile_id_form_db` in aht0 and after this return to frontend user. What it will give me is that I have already create profile, JWT has custom claim base on what I can validate who he is and my backend do not need to make some checks is profile exists every request.

I get to the point where I'm passing `redirect_uri` to my backend callback endpoint

```
auth: {
    domain,
    clientId,
    authorizationParams: {
      ...(audience && audience !== 'YOUR_API_IDENTIFIER' ? { audience } : null),
      redirect_uri: "https://localhost:7170/Test/callback",
      code_challenge_method,
      code_challenge
    },
```

But I have no idea how to handle code and state queryParams in this callback.

On other hand I found in Auth0 dashboard place where you can implement
`onExecutePostUserRegistration` action. But this but this approach seems to me so clumsy and difficult and making the entire flow very dependent on integration with Auth0 and not the OAuth standard.

My question in with direction I should go.

Maybe I should do something like this that Web API allow only send request to createProfile endpoint with out custom claim in JWT, where I will create user, set his id to user claims, and when user will need to relogin to get new JWT with custom claim to be able to use API ?

Comment: use the auth0 action [onExecutePostUserRegistration](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/flows-and-triggers/post-user-registration-flow#store-the-auth0-user-id-in-a-remote-system). It's not clumsy, it's simple and it should accomplish your exact requirement.

Comment: unfortunately, I found information that https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/flows-and-triggers/post-user-registration-flow "The post-user-registration triggers runs after a user has been created for a Database or Passwordless connection. " 
This will not work with all socialmedia registration.;/